# ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function in MySQL update

Tags: mysql, sql-update, inner-join

```
update
  table1 a
  inner join table2 b on a.unique_id = b.unique_id
set
  a.menu_return = sum(
    case when b.value1 = 'mainmenu'
    and b.value2 = '0' then 1 else 0 end
  )
where
  a.time_stamp >= '2021-12-17 00:00:00'
  and a.time_stamp < '2021-12-18 00:00:00';
```

ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function

What cause this issue?

Comment: You cannot use aggregate function in SET clause. Use it in datasource clause (use subquery).

Comment: You need `GROUP BY` if you're aggregating, but `GROUP BY` isn't allowed in `UPDATE` queries.

Comment: @Barmar , I cant use `GROUP BY` in this query.

Comment: You have to do it in a subquery, as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really understand what you try to achieve by this query, but looks as you need to use join with pre-aggregated query like:

```
update  table1 a
    inner join (
      select 
        unique_id,  
        sum( case when value1 = 'mainmenu' and value2 = '0' then 1 else 0 end ) menu_return
        from table2 
        group by unique_id
    ) b on a.unique_id = b.unique_id
    set
      a.menu_return = b.menu_return
    where
      a.time_stamp >= '2021-12-17 00:00:00' and a.time_stamp < '2021-12-18 00:00:00';
```

You can [play with MySQL online here](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql57/de0da973e0df1e98cdfd8f6c65b738ff/)